# Nomenclature of catenanes and rotaxanes

Tags: nomenclature, supramolecular-chemistry

Looking at the IUPAC Blue Book, I noticed that the words “catenane”, “rotaxane” (or “interlocked”, “mechanical bond”, …) do not appear within the rules of nomenclature. Given that a catenane or rotaxane is typically considered a single molecule, I was wondering how these compounds are named. I have read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenane) that catenanes with *n* bonds are referred to as a [*n*]-catenanes… but how are specific compounds named?

Comment: See also [Nomenclature for rotaxanes and pseudorotaxanes (IUPAC Recommendations 2008)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac200880092041)